# Reactjs Redux persist : It is possible to persist my Redux store in a file system?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I'm working on a React/Redux and redux-persist project, I want to know if it's possible to persist my store in a file (example.txt for example) instead of Localstorage or indexedDb, because I have a big amount of data and Google Chrome trigger an out of memory error when I try to persist it in indexedDb

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say no, but after some research, it looks like "maybe". You might be able to leverage the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API). I've never used it, so can't vouch for it. Apparently you need to get direct permission from the user, and probably would need to on every visit to the site.

How large is your data? It's possible indexed DB may work, but you need to use blobs or chunk your data differently.

Comment: ~ 700Mb is the size of my store, and chrome trigger an out of memory when I'm trying to persist store in indexedDb..

Comment: Have you an example with the File System Access API ?

Comment: You might be able to get ~700mb if you use the proper settings, Indexed DB can go quite large. See [here](https://web.dev/storage-for-the-web/). An no, as I said I've never used it myself, but the documentation I linked should give examples.

Comment: The problem with indexedDb is it create only one key value, and store ALL my 700mb data in this value's field, so chrome trigger the out of memory exception

Comment: so split it up?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it haha'

Comment: Then open another question for that :) Indexed DB is a bit unintuitive, but there are some libraries to help with it. In the new question you ask, make sure to give info on the memory limits you need and browsers you need to support.

Comment: Surely not all 700mb describe the current state of the application.  I would persist only the data which directly describes the application state and the rest can be derived when the app is mounted.

Answer (score 1):

Check this docs : https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

There are too many storage engines:

```
## Storage Engines
localStorage import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
sessionStorage import storageSession from 'redux-persist/lib/storage/session'
electron storage Electron support via electron store
redux-persist-cookie-storage Cookie storage engine, works in browser and Node.js, for universal / isomorphic apps
redux-persist-expo-filesystem react-native, similar to redux-persist-filesystem-storage but does not require linking or ejecting CRNA/Expo app. Only available if using Expo SDK (Expo, create-react-native-app, standalone).
redux-persist-expo-securestore react-native, for sensitive information using Expo's SecureStore. Only available if using Expo SDK (Expo, create-react-native-app, standalone).
redux-persist-fs-storage react-native-fs engine
redux-persist-filesystem-storage react-native, to mitigate storage size limitations in android (#199, #284) redux-persist-indexeddb-storage recommended for web via localForage
redux-persist-node-storage for use in nodejs environments.
redux-persist-pouchdb Storage engine for PouchDB.
redux-persist-sensitive-storage react-native, for sensitive information (uses react-native-sensitive-info).
redux-persist-weapp-storage Storage engine for wechat mini program, also compatible with wepy
redux-persist-webextension-storage Storage engine for browser (Chrome, Firefox) web extension storage
@bankify/redux-persist-realm Storage engine for Realm database, you will need to install Realm first
custom any conforming storage api implementing the following methods: setItem getItem removeItem. (NB: These methods must support promises)
```

Looks like file-system is supported onlu in react-native but you could use different databases